# Time of the day in minutes Java

Tags: java, datetime, time

I am looking to calculate the number of minutes given the time of the day.

Eg.: when input is 11:34, the output should be 11*60+34. The date doesn't matter.

I only need it down to the minutes scale. Seconds, milliseconds... don't matter.
Is there a method somewhere in Java doing this the neat way without me calculating it?

Right now, i'm using `theTime.split(":")`, `theTime` is a `String` holding "11:34" here, parsing the integers on each side and doing the calculation.

I saw [`Time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) but what I'm doing right now seemed more direct.

Nothing in [`Systems`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) either.

Comment: Is there a problem here? It sounds like your solution works fine. No, there is not a standard method in Java that will get the time of day in minutes.

Answer (score 8):

There is no build in method for it. However here is a one-liner for it:

```
int timeInMins = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 60 + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your approach looks good and sound, however to answer your question it would be simple to say that there is no such build in method which does that. You have to calculate it the way you are doing it right now.

Answer (score 2):

Hi maybe you could use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)? Below example how to get number of minutes from parsed string and from current time. In java 8 there is similar [api](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) but I haven't found exactly method like minutesOfDay()

```
@Test
public void learnHowManyMinutesPassedToday() {
   DateTime time = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm").parseDateTime("11:34");
   System.out.println(time.getMinuteOfDay());

   System.out.println(DateTime.now().getMinuteOfDay());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to have input not from a String, take a look at

> Java.util.Calendar.

It has Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY and Calendar.HOUR and Calendar.MINUTE which could be your input. I'm not sure what the "neat" way of doing this would be. It is a simple calculation.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = rightNow.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int min  = rightNow.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    System.out.println("TimeMinutes:" + hour * 60 + min);
```

EDIT:
Except using split use the above.

Comment: Please add an explanation of how your code solves the problem, so that your answer is clearer to people who need guidance.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Arkanon  Did you really down this post because of that? I believe it was actually obvious. He was using split to get minutes instead he can use this.

Comment: @user503413 Did you down the post? I believe it was actually obvious. He was using split to get minutes instead he can use this.

Comment: @Rika no, I didn't down the post - usually I post the reason I downed it and pointing clearly why I downed it in the first place. You should start a witch hunt to see who down voted, better look into what the comments are saying and improving your response. As you can see, this is a quite meritocratic and open community and each of its members has the right to up/down vote a question/response if they find it fit to do so. So...to conclude as a recommendation look at other high voted responses and see how they look then start following that direction on your posts.

Comment: @Rika No, I did not downvote the post, and please do not post multiple comments asking for various people to confess to downvoting. I ask you to add an explanation to your code because Stack Overflow is supposed to be an encyclopaedic reference where people can learn what causes a problem and why a solution works. Adding an explanation makes an answer much more valuable to visitors to the site.

Comment: Okay, now I have downvoted your answer because I believe it to be incorrect. You are fetching the number of minutes from the Calendar, but I believe that this will only fetch the number of minutes from the current hour, and the question asker wants the total number of minutes elapsed in the whole day so far, not just the current hour.

Comment: @user503413 Just to say sorry for any offense.

Comment: @Arkanon Just to say sorry for any offense. I actually thought you were the one who downvoted because you commented first. I honestly don't like any downvoting on anythng because people sometimes or most of time people do it for the wrong reasons and just too quickly without thinking what the person was trying to do or say. But back to the question at hand, one of things he wanted was a parse for a given time like 11:34; if you use Calendar.Hour it will give 11; if you use Calendar.Minutes it will give you 34; My answer was like a step in the right direction. 11 * 60 + 34. Thanks

Comment: @Rika A downvote is usually given in the hope of persuading the poster to edit their answer to improve it or, in the worst cases, to delete an answer which cannot be salvaged. You can always edit your own answers and should feel free to do so whenever you think you can make an improvement. If you edit your answer to fit with what the question asker is trying to achieve then I will remove my downvote (and hopefully so will the mystery downvoter).